# Getting the load for each job

Tags: slurm

Where can I find the load (used/claimed CPUs) per job? I know to get it per host using `sinfo`, but that does not directly give information on which job causes a possible 'incorrect' load of anything unequal to 1.

(I want to get this for all jobs, i.e. logging in to the node and running `top` is not my objective.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
sacct --format='jobid,ReqCPUS,elapsed,AveCPU'
```

and compare `Elapsed` with `AveCPU`. The latter will only be available for job steps, not for the whole job.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In my cast the `AveCPU` field is completely empty...? Also, I'd prefer to be able to see this for all users (not just myself).

Comment: What is the output of `scontrol show config | grep JobAcctGatherType` ? If it is `none` then Slurm is not configured to collect that information. It it is not, then make sure to start your tasks with `srun`. As for seeing the others' jobs, use `sacct -a`

Comment: Thanks, in principle your answer is comprehensive. Just not what I was hoping for. I do not want to rely on submitting with `srun`. Also, `sacct -a` is limiting slow. I still believe though that the information that I want is somehow available to SLURM. Before, when I used PBS I could just get this from the equivalent of `squeue` (`qstat -f`).

Comment: `qstat` is available from `slurm-torque` RPM maybe it does that?

Comment: I can try, do you know where I can download the source from, such that I can compile it in my home folder?